# How does one deal with an ever accumulating tab count?

Tags: browser, feed

I find that I open sites like Hacker News and click a bunch of links in new tabs but then I don't have time to read all of them at a time. These accumulate in a sort of reading debt. I don't want to close them because they're interesting, but I'll never get around to them because I'll always open new tabs each time I do have time to read, and I read some of those new ones instead. How do I get out of this pattern?

Comment: Close tabs.. =]

Comment: There are add-ons that will save the links if the problem is too many open tabs.  If the issue is a compulsion to accumulate reading material, that really isn't a computer hardware or software problem.  If the issue is what to do with the saved stuff, you need to cull and/or read it, or buy a lot storage capacity.  The first step is to define the nature of the problem and decide what you want to do about it.  You could continue to just save the stuff and not do anything about it now.  Eventually, you will retire and then you can go through it at your leasure and wonder why you ever saved it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add them to a reading list.

Chrome and Firefox have browser extensions for that.

Chrome:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-reading-list/agkngimeadfopogepmpkofdbfllhdnbi?hl=en

Firefox:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-reading-list-noosfeer/

Safari has a feature like this built in.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200294

Microsoft Edge has one as well:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-10/getstarted-take-your-reading-with-you

Not sure about Internet Explorer